# Labelling output from lapply in R

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R (have been using SAS/Stata until now) and I use it mainly for biostatistics.

I am trying to run a univariate linear regression on 20-ish explanatory variables and move those of which have a p-value <0.15 to a multiple regression.

In attempting to do this a bit more efficiently, I have created a data subset with the explanatory variables and another subset with only the outcome variable. Then, I am using

`my_lms<-lapply(seq_length(ncol), function(i) lm(Fl[,1] ~ Ex[,20])`

and to get the summary I am using:

`summaries <- lapply(my_lms, summary)`

However, I find that with the summaries, they do not give me any indication of the column names for each outputted result. Rather, it just gives me the column number in square brackets (eg, [[12]]). It is quite bothersome to work out which variables correspond to which output and could make me prone to error. Is there anyway to get this command to label the summaries with the explanatory variable column names that they were generated from?

Thanks!

Comment: You can just do: `names(summaries) <- x`, where `x` is the vector of names you want to assign

Comment: Ah okay, it would be nice if there were a more convenient way of retaining the more information that is there. However, in the absence of that I will give that go.

Comment: Also, using the above, I realised that the summaries output does not give me 95% confidence intervals for the beta-coefficient. Is there a way to get that outputted efficiently?

Comment: For anyone curious, I think I worked it out. You can do it like this: 

`lapply(my_lms, confint)`

Comment: using `sapply(..., simplify=FALSE)` might help you keep the names - although likely you will need to redo your approach slightly . so if `mpg` is your outcome: `memods <- sapply(names(mtcars)[-1], function(x) lm(reformulate(x, "mpg"), data=mtcars), simplify=FALSE)` keeps the names

Answer (score 1):

Instead of separating your data into different data frames, keep a single data frame and feed `lapply` the column names of the predictor variables. Below is an example using the built-in `mtcars` data frame.

```
my_lms = lapply(names(mtcars)[-grep("mpg", names(mtcars))], function(n) {
  lm(paste("mpg ~ ", n), data=mtcars)
})
```

Then you can print summaries or confidence intervals and the actual column names of the variables will appear in the output.

```
lapply(my_lms, summary)
lapply(my_lms, confint)
```

In the code above to generate the models, we use the `data` argument to tell `lm` which data frame to use. Then we use the column names in the model formula, which can be entered, as we do here, using a string instead of formula expression. With this approach, the actual variable names appear in the summary output.

As you noted, grabbing vectors from one or more data frames within the model formula results in the column names of the model variables not being included in the summary. It also results in some ancillary functions not working properly. For example:

```
m1 = lm(mtcars[,1] ~ mtcars[,6])
predict(m1, newdata=data.frame(wt=1:10))
```

This results in a warning `Warning message: 'newdata' had 10 rows but variables found have 32 rows` and `predict` outputs predictions using the data that was used to fit the model rather than the new data we entered into the function.

If you use a named vector of column names, then the list elements output by `lapply` will be named. This makes it possible to generate single data frames containing the output of multiple models with a column added that marks which model a given row belongs to. For example:

```
library(broom)
library(purrr)

vars = names(mtcars)[-grep("mpg", names(mtcars))]

my_lms = lapply(setNames(vars, vars), function(n) {
  lm(paste("mpg ~ ", n), data=mtcars)
})

map_df(my_lms, tidy, .id="Predictor Variable")
```

> ```
>    Predictor Variable        term    estimate    std.error  statistic      p.value
> 1                 cyl (Intercept) 37.88457649  2.073843606 18.2678078 8.369155e-18
> 2                 cyl         cyl -2.87579014  0.322408883 -8.9196988 6.112687e-10
> 3                disp (Intercept) 29.59985476  1.229719515 24.0704115 3.576586e-21
> 4                disp        disp -0.04121512  0.004711833 -8.7471515 9.380327e-10
> 5                  hp (Intercept) 30.09886054  1.633920950 18.4212465 6.642736e-18
> 6                  hp          hp -0.06822828  0.010119304 -6.7423885 1.787835e-07
> 7                drat (Intercept) -7.52461844  5.476662574 -1.3739423 1.796391e-01
> 8                drat        drat  7.67823260  1.506705108  5.0960421 1.776240e-05
> 9                  wt (Intercept) 37.28512617  1.877627337 19.8575753 8.241799e-19
> 10                 wt          wt -5.34447157  0.559101045 -9.5590441 1.293959e-10
> 11               qsec (Intercept) -5.11403815 10.029543299 -0.5098974 6.138544e-01
> 12               qsec        qsec  1.41212484  0.559210130  2.5252133 1.708199e-02
> 13                 vs (Intercept) 16.61666667  1.079711283 15.3899167 8.846603e-16
> 14                 vs          vs  7.94047619  1.632370025  4.8643850 3.415937e-05
> 15                 am (Intercept) 17.14736842  1.124602541 15.2474922 1.133983e-15
> 16                 am          am  7.24493927  1.764421632  4.1061270 2.850207e-04
> 17               gear (Intercept)  5.62333333  4.916379125  1.1437957 2.617534e-01
> 18               gear        gear  3.92333333  1.308130699  2.9991906 5.400948e-03
> 19               carb (Intercept) 25.87233385  1.836807218 14.0854923 9.218370e-15
> 20               carb        carb -2.05571870  0.568545640 -3.6157497 1.084446e-03
> ```

To gather other model information, you can do, for example:

```
map_df(my_lms, confint_tidy, .id="Predictor Variable")
map_df(my_lms, augment, .id="Predictor Variable")
map_df(my_lms, glance, .id="Predictor Variable")
```

**UPDATE:** In response to the comment:

1. What does `names(mtcars)[-grep("mpg", names(mtcars))]` do?

   `names(mtcars)` returns a vector with all of the names, but we want to exclude `mpg`, because that's the outcome variable. `grep("mpg", names(mtcars))` returns the index position of `mpg` in the `mtcars` data frame, which happens to be `1`, because `mpg` is the first column of the data frame. So, `names(mtcars)[-grep("mpg", names(mtcars))]` is equivalent to `names(mtcars)[-1]`, which means return a vector of all the column names of `mtcars` except for the value at position 1. However, we used `grep` because it allows us to exclude a column with a given name, without having to know its index position in the data frame. You can achieve the same result with `names(mtcars)[-match("mpg", names(mtcars))]`.

   (In fact, the latter is safer because `names(mtcars)[-grep("mpg", names(mtcars))]` will exclude any column that includes `mpg` as part of its name; to force `grep` to match only `mpg` you can do `grep("^mpg$", names(mtcars))`, but that gets into details of string matching that maybe you don't want to worry about right now.)

   You can see how these functions work by running the parts separately. For example, run `grep("mpg", names(mtcars))`.
2. Why do you have to put the argument vars in twice at: `setNames(vars, vars)`?

   `vars` is a vector of column names. `setNames(vars, vars)` assigns a name to each element of the vector. (Run `setNames(vars, vars)` to see the output and compare how it differs from just `vars`. `setNames` takes two arguments. The first is the object for which you want to set the names. The second argument is the names you want to assign. `setNames(vars, LETTERS[1:length(vars)])` would assign the first 10 letters of the alphabet as the names.) This results in `lapply` using these names as the names of the list elements in `my_lms`. It would be nice if `lapply` just named the output list elements with the input `vars` values by default, but it doesn't. A way to avoid `setNames` is to use `sapply` instead of `lapply`, but then you have to add the argument `simplify=FALSE`.

   ```
   my_lms = sapply(vars, function(n) {
     lm(paste("mpg ~ ", n), data=mtcars)
   }, simplify=FALSE)
   ```
3. How do you know which variables R will run a linear regression on with `mpg` when you use: `lm(paste("mpg ~ ", n)`?

   Look at the `sapply` function just above, which creates `my_lms`: `sapply` and `lapply` take an input vector or list (`vars` in this case) and run a function on each element of that input vector or list. In this case, we specify that the function to run is `lm`. `n` is a "dummy" argument that refers back to the input vector `vars`. So, in the first iteration of the function `n` is the first element of `vars`, which is `cyl`. In the second iteration, `n` is `disp`, etc.
4. `map_df` is a function from the `purrr` package (which is part of the `tidyverse` suite of packages). `map` is equivalent to `lapply` or `sapply`. `map_df` is convenient because it returns a data frame rather than a list.

For learning more about all this stuff, you might find the free book [`R for Data Science`](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/) helpful.

Comment: Hi this appears to be a great answer but may be a little beyond my R experience.

In particular, what does the code 

`names(mtcars)[-grep("mpg", names(mtcars))]`

do? I'm only used to using names with names(vector) <- namesvector

Also why do you have to put the argument vars in twice at: 

`setNames(vars, vars)`

Also, how do you know which variables R will run a linear regression on with mpg when you use: 

`lm(paste("mpg ~ ", n), data=mtcars)`

Lastly, what function is: 

`map_df()` 

I have no documentation when I type ?map_df into R
Sorry for basic questions